# Remove KDE greeter and install lightdm

Tags: lightdm

So I had installed multiple desktop environments, later removing them, however the greater was still there, in attempt to remove the greeter (KDE), I have actually removed lightdm. So how would I reinstall lightdm from terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You can install lightdm by:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

If you want to set lightdm as the default one, run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

click "OK" and select lightdm