# failed to start Light Display Manager

Tags: lightdm, display-manager

I am very new to Ubuntu. I am getting [failed to start Light Display Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXByO.jpg) error when I start Ubuntu. I am not getting login page. It might be possible that I have **deleted Lightdm** package. Can I **download** it again using any command with proper link? It is not available in computer so I could not install it.

Comment: What do you mean by not available in computer?

Comment: You can install lightdm with this command `sudo apt-get install lightdm` though!

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if you have lightdm installed:

```
lightdm -v
```

Install lightdm from your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

PS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> should grant you access to the console even if you do not have any screen icons

Comment: Fwiw `apt-get` is deprecated in favour of `apt`.

Comment: After installing lightdm, if you want to setup lightdm default, use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, click *OK* and select lightdm. [ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/630656/300619)

Comment: Thankyou sir, after following your suggestion i am getting fooling error:

Comment: I got this during install : " package lightdm is not available,but is referred to by another package.this may mean that the package is missing,has been obsoleted,or is only available from another source. "

Comment: Be sure to `apt-get update`